# Google Analytics get uncaught exceptions via email

Tags: android, email, google-analytics, automatic-updates

I am using Google Analytics to get uncaught exceptions. But to view these exceptions you need to every time login and see if there was any uncaught exceptions.

So I tried Google Analytics automatic email service. This feature can be configured from Behavior >> Crashes and Exceptions >> Email. You can insert your email address to get **Daily/Weekly/Monthly/Quarterly** mails.

But the problem with the above mail is that it only reports number of exceptions occurred to the user. It does not report which exceptions occurred on the daily basis.

Can we get exception stack trace in these daily mails ?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I wonder if custom reports can help solve your problem? (Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21718577/3664487)

Comment: In addition, my question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500003/can-google-analytics-email-me-if-crashes-and-exceptions-occur) seems closely related.