# Where can I see the google analytics exceptions I am logging

Tags: google-analytics

I am logging google analytics exceptions:

ga.exception({ description: description, fatal });

but I do not see where these exceptions are in the analytics GUI.

Is there anything I need to configure to see these errors.

I cannot find where they should be

Answer (score 6):

GA > Customization > Dashboards > Create > Create Dashboard > Under 'Show the following metric:' search for 'exceptions'

[image]

Comment: great, then how can i view then

Comment: while this is a feature I don't use myself I did manage to find [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718481/report-for-exceptions-from-google-analytics-analytics-js-exception-tracking). although it's a few years old, hopefully it can lead you down the right path.

Comment: It seems like this is deprecated. New versions of google analytics is just totally different, no "dashboard" option in customization.