# Catch javascript errors inside google analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I want the window.onerror handler to be called when an error occures inside the "ga(function(tracker)" function. Apparently the ga function has it's own error handler which prevents the window.onerror handler to be invoked.

```js
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

window.onerror = function() {console.log('Hello world') };
    
ga('create', '********', '********');
ga(function(tracker) {
console.log('Start');
/* 
Variable y is undefined 
window.onerror should be invoked
*/
var x = y;
console.log('End');
});
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Just to be clear. My question is NOT how to track errors with google analytics but how to catch errors inside google analytics scripting.

Comment: you can use google tag manager [onerror](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679411?hl=en) or check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21718577/14135825) answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Report for exceptions from Google Analytics analytics.js exception tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21718481/report-for-exceptions-from-google-analytics-analytics-js-exception-tracking)

Comment: @MichelePisani Thanks for replying. No my question is not how to track javascript errors with google analytics but how to track errors inside the javascript of google analytics.

Comment: What kind of error would you like to track within the analytics code?

Comment: @MichelePisani All errors. If an error occurs inside this part of the script it is possible a pageview/event/etc is not send to google analytics. We track all javascript errors on our website via the window.onerror event. However for some reason the window.onerror is not invoked for errors inside the ga scripts. This means it can take a while before we notice a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using custom `try..catch` and `dispatchEvent` would help:

```
    
ga('create', '********', '********');

// declaring readyCallback function
var initFunction = function(tracker) {
console.log('Start');
/* 
Variable y is undefined 
window.onerror should be invoked
*/
var x = y;
console.log('End');
}

// Wrapping your readyCallback with custom try...catch:
var initFunctionWrapped = function (tracker) {
  try {
    initFunction(tracker)
  } catch (e) {
    var event = new Event('error', e);
    window.dispatchEvent(event)
}

ga(initFunctionWrapped);
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: If the initFunction returns an error why is it caught using the initFunctionWrapped function but not caught if called directly by the window.onerror handler?

Comment: If you don't use `dispatchEvent` any error in `readyCallback` will be caught by `ga` inner try...catch and won't propagate to `window`